# Posting Comments on Facebook Live Video

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a comment on live videos,

I'm getting error when i am POST over to /{live_video_id}/comments

> Unsupported post request. Object with ID '4273758699413587' does not
> exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
> support this operation.

But when i do a GET request /{live_video_id}/comments i am able to get it.

I already added in the permission etc but still am getting error, am i using the wrong endpoint for this action?

This is the one i'm using:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/comments/

These are all the permissions i enabled:
pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_engagement, user_link, pages_read_user_content, pages_show_list, user_posts, pages_messaging, user_videos, Live Video API

Comment: If you use same video id on get and it works, problems maybe in permissions.

Comment: Is your token a _"A Page access token requested by a person who can perform the MODERATE task on the Page"_, as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/#publish says?

Answer (score 0):

If we can get video id then its possible. I implemented this by using the get posts API on Facebook page ({pageid}/videos), which gives me list of posts on Facebook Page I filter the posts response to get video id using the title of post, but it taking long time.

[image]
[image]